# Stored Procedure Update Process in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2013

I am new to using Visual Studio 2013 and am coming over from Visual Studio 2010. A very big change I noticed is in the way VS 2013 updates stored procedures as opposed to the way VS 2010 does it.

In VS 2010, when a stored procedure opened that already existed, the script action is `ALTER PROCEDURE`, however in VS 2013, whether the stored procedure exists or not, the script action is `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

Then, if I want to update the stored procedure in VS 2013, I need to click on the update button in the upper left of the script and deal with additional workflow. For me, the stored procedure workflow process in VS 2010 is streamlined and easy to use and in VS 2013 the stored procedure workflow process is cumbersome and hard to use.

I have looked around and can't find a way to reconfigure VS 2013 stored procedure workflow. Does anyone know how to get it to work like it does in VS 2010?

Thanks.

Comment: marc_s, well, what you describe is not the way it works.  No matter if the proc exists or doesn't exist, it's still CREATE PROCEDURE.  The problem is that the nitty-gritty details are now on my plate with VS 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to make sure this got answered so that in case anybody else comes in here looking for an answer gets one.

The real issue was that in VS2010, I could simply click on the save icon and the proc would immediately get saved.  In VS2013, you have to click twice, once to generate a dialog box with some options and then again to actually save the proc to the database which runs a script that is generated to update the proc.

I was confused by the extra steps and once I got used to it, it became a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue.

Solution was to right click on the DB project on VS 2013, select **Publish**, and fill out the popup (mainly the target DB, name of table, etc.)

This will update the stored procedure in the target DB, and then you go pop into your SQL manager and run it if you want.

Notice: SQL might complain about not being able to run CLR (if you add a CLR SP). If that's the case, running:

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled',1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled'  -- make sure it took
GO
```

should fix that.

Hope this helps.